# php file with html in it is commenting out php

Tags: php, html

Hi I have the following code and the browser is commenting out the php. The file is saved .php however nothing helps. I've searched this forum and nothing works.

```
<html>
    <head>

    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>-->
        <title>
            Golden Acres
        </title>
        <link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    </head>
    <body class="center">
        <table class="main_tables">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" >
                    <img class="main_logo" src="images/logo2.gif" alt="logo"/>
                </td>
                <td id="main_nav_menu"  valign="bottom">
                    <table cellspacing="2" >
                        <tr>
                            <td id="slogan_home" colspan="6" valign="middle">
                                "delivering fresh close to your home"

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="extra_row"><td></td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="main_nav_menu" align="center">
                                <a class="main_nav_menu_links"  href="index.html">home</a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="main_nav_menu">
                                <a class="main_nav_menu_links"  href="about_us.html">about us</a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="main_nav_menu" >
                                <a class="main_nav_menu_links" href="boxes.html">boxes</a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="main_nav_menu">
                                <a class="main_nav_menu_links" href="shop.html">Shop</a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="main_nav_menu">
                                <a class="main_nav_menu_links" href="events.html">events</a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="main_nav_menu">
                                <a class="main_nav_menu_links" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $submit = $_POST['submit'];

            if(isset($_POST['register_fname'])&&($_POST['register_lname'])&&($_POST['register_uname'])&&($_POST['register_password'])){
                $firstname = $_POST['register_fname'];
                $lastname = $_POST['register_lname'];
                $username = $_POST['register_uname'];
                $password = $_POST['register_password'];

                if(isset($firstname)&&isset($lastname)&&isset($username)&&isset($password)){
                    echo 'Isset is ok';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'Isset is not ok';
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
        <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The when I inspect element in the browser it's displayed as : `<!-- php .... ?-->`

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you accessing the file through a server, or with a `file://` URL?

Comment: If you're accessing it through a server, it's a server config problem: it's not configured to run PHP.

Comment: The browser most likely is not commenting your PHP. I would say this happens on the server. Are you sure your server is set up to serve PHP?

Comment: Through xampp. However I've already done several php files with form on this server and all php was executed. If it's a php server config issue, can someone guide me on what to do please ?

Comment: For god sakes forget table-web-design.

Answer (score 0):

add at the begins of the page before Html and even DOCTYPE declaration tag :

```
<?php include "register.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

and move your code to this file < register.php >

then use the form like this:

```
<form id="" name="" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" role="form">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" >
</form>
```

i hope this will help

Comment: If his server is not properly executing `<?php` tags, why do you think it will execute the `include`?

Comment: i assumed that his server executing php tags.
i have faced problem similar to this before with one of my project while making a contact form, and solved by removing my code to another file then just to use include.

Comment: `<!-- php` is always the result of the server not executing the PHP tags. It's what the browser does when the response contains literal `<?php`, which the PHP processor would never leave in the result.

Comment: I will try what you said Ahmed and Thanks for your replies. However the browser is commenting out all the php tags. Any hints of what needs to be done from the server to help this ?

Comment: just try and tell me what will happen, so i can help if it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this was a silly mistake of mine.